# Link to latest poll?

Tags: routes, polls

I set up my poll tpl file to include the poll fields (form, results, etc) along with a list at the bottom for the previous polls, ordered by date.  What I am trying to do is, from the main menu, link to the latest poll.  In other words, my current latest poll is node/123456/.  I can link to that, obviously.  But when we create a new one, that link needs to be updated.  I'd love to have it so the menu item doesn't need to be edited each time a new poll is created.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Just so you don't think I'm waiting expecting you to write it for me - this is where I am:

`$items['poll/latest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Latest Poll',
    'page callback' => 'latest_poll_find_poll',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );`

return $items;

/**
 * Find latest poll and redirect user
 */
function latest_poll_find_poll() {
  $nid = db_query('SELECT MAX(nid) AS nid FROM {node} WHERE type = "poll"')->fetchField();
  $latest = is_numeric($nid) ? 'node/' . $nid : '';
  drupal_goto($latest);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a small custom module that implements `hook_menu()` and a custom callback that determines the latest poll and redirects the user.  Something like this perhaps (for D6, D7 will be similar):

**Drupal 7**

---

MYMODULE.info

```
name = "MYMODULE"
description = "Adds a menu item for the most recent poll"
core = 7.x
```

MYMODULE.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['poll/latest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Latest Poll',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_find_poll',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Find latest poll and redirect user
 */
function MYMODULE_find_poll() {
  $nid = db_query('SELECT MAX(nid) AS nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type', array(':type' => 'poll'))->fetchField();
  $latest = is_numeric($nid) ? 'node/' . $nid : '<front>';
  drupal_goto($latest);
}
```

**Drupal 6**

---

MYMODULE.info

```
name = "MYMODULE"
description = "Adds a menu item for the most recent poll"
core = 6.x
```

MYMODULE.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['poll/latest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Latest Poll',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_find_poll',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Find latest poll and redirect user
 */
function MYMODULE_find_poll() {
  $nid = db_result(db_query('SELECT MAX(nid) AS nid FROM {node} WHERE type = "poll"'));
  $latest = is_numeric($nid) ? 'node/' . $nid : '<front>';
  drupal_goto($latest);
}
```

Replacing "MYMODULE" with the name of your custom module and placing those files in your site's modules directory in a folder named MYMODULE (replace of course).

Comment: Awesome, will give this a shot.  Always shy away from building my own modules for things, but it doesn't seem too complicated.  Should have mentioned D7, btw.

Comment: OK - so I added that module and enabled it.  Only change I made was what seemed to be a stray "}" under "return $items."

Now, how do I add it to the menu?  I tried directing the menu item to "poll/latest" but that just gives me a list of the polls.

Comment: Ah my bad, some code got cut out... not sure how that happened, edited answer.  You will need to change the database query to be compatible with D7 as the Database API has changed.  The `hook_menu()` function is where it gets added to the menu

Comment: @Mike updated answer for both versions if you needed it. I'm at the point where I need to learn more D7 anyway ;)

Comment: That did it - you are the man!  And now I understand how to use hook_menu.  Thanks a lot!!